# how to deploy a maven dependency to WildFly

Tags: maven, wildfly, eclipse-jee

I'm trying to understand how to tell WildFly through maven, that certain libraries are needed.
I have a maven project in eclipse-jee. When I call a JSP, which's backing class works alone, everything is ok. But when I call a JSP, which's backing class uses a class from a library, I get a ClassNotFoundException. When I run that backing class locally instead of on the server, it works perfectly.
The library is added as maven dependency, which is fine as long as I stay local. But when I deploy the WAR to WildFly, the library isn't deployed.

Here's my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>hello_neo4j</name>
  <artifactId>myNeo4j</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.SP1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <groupId>com.my-domain</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

As soon as I try to instantiate *org.neo4j.driver.Config*, I get:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.driver.Config from [Module "deployment.hello_neo4j.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 59 more
```

So, how can I tell eclipse, that it should either package the library in the WAR or deploy it along with the WAR?
I guess, somewhere in the POM should be anything telling that the dependency is to be deployed, but I don't know how. 
In the *effective POM*, I see `<scope>compile</scope>` and I thought, it would mean that the dependency would be compiled into the POM. But obviously, I need something more, but what?

Thanks in advance for your helpful comments!

Answer (score -1):

before posting the question, I had searched really long... But now, short after posting it, I found the answer: Just another dependency is needed in order to enable the server to resolve the dependencies from the deployed POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Hope, this might help others to search a shorter time than I did.

Comment: That plugin is used to deploy to a maven repository not WildFly.